# Applescript: Open preview "Export to pdf" error: Preview got an error: Can’t get keystroke " "

Tags: applescript

I would like to open all the pdfs in a folder with preview and export them to another folder using "Export to PDF".

This is my issue so far.

## Error

> Preview got an error: Can’t get keystroke "
> ".

## Apple Script

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/documents/PDFs" as alias list
end tell
repeat with f in fl
    tell application "Preview"
        open f
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
            delay 0.2
            click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
        keystroke return
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `keystroke return` is a system events command and you have it within the "Preview tell block"

It looks as if your intention of `keystroke return` is to actually click the "Save" button, then this should work for you...

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
        delay 0.2
        click menu item "Export as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 0.2
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```